Estimate of Fourier coefficients of $x^{-1/4}$
I'm studying whether the function $f(x)=x^{-1/4}$ on $[0,1]$ has $p$-summable Fourier coefficients for some $1<p<2$, i.e., $(\widehat{f}(n))_{n\in \mathbb{Z}}\in \ell^p(\mathbb{Z}).$ Apparently, $f$ has 2-summable Fourier coefficients since $f\in L^2(\mathbb{T})$, but does not have absolutely summable Fourier coefficients since $f$ is not continuous on $[0,1]$. Is there any way that we can estimate the Fourier coefficient of $f$? Any feedback or reference would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Why not take $N$ equally distributed points over [0,1] and compute the discrete fourier and see how the points closest to $1/k$ are as $n \to \infty$?

The Fourier coefficients of $x^{-1/4}$ are not $p$-summable for $p\le {4\over 3}.$ Indeed by the Hausdorff-Young inequality the mapping $T(\{a_n\})=\sum a_ne^{2\pi i nx}$ is a bounded linear operator from $\ell^p$ to $L^q(0,1)$ for $1\le p\le 2$ and $p^{-1}+q^{-1}=1.$  As $f(x):=x^{-1/4}\notin L^q$ for $q\ge 4$ then $\{\widehat{f}(n)\}\notin \ell^p$ for $p\le{4\over 3}.$
I believe that $\{\widehat{x^{-1/4}}(n)\}$ belongs to the weak $L^{4/3,\infty}$ space. Then by the Marcinkiewicz interpolation theorem it would belong to $\ell^p$ for $p>4/3.$
Remark One can apply the Hausdorff-Young inequality for the mapping $$Sf=\{\widehat{f}(n)\}_{n=-\infty}^\infty,$$ which gives
$$\left (\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \widehat{f}(n)^{q}\right )^{1/q}\le \|f\|_p,$$ where  $1\le p\le 2,$ $p^{-1}+q^{-1}=1.$ However for the function $f(x)=x^{-1/4}$ the inequality does not give anything essential for the OP problem, as $q\ge 2$ and $\ell^q(\mathbb{Z})\subset \ell^2(\mathbb{Z}).$

Thanks for the comment. I'm a little confused how you Hausdorff-Young inequality here. Shouldn't p has to be between 1 and 2, so that we have  | \widehat{f}(n)|{\ell^{p'}} \leq C |f|{L^p(\mathbb{T})}  for some C>0?

The Hausdorff-Young inequality holds for the mappings $L^q(0,1)$ to $\ell^p(\mathbb{Z})$ and  $\ell^q(\mathbb{Z})$ to $L^p(0,1),$ in both cases $1\le p\le 1$ and $p^{-1}+q^{-1}=1.$ However for the second mapping the information is not useful for $f(x)=x^{-1/4}$ as $q\ge 2,$ so we do not get any summability of ${\widehat{f}(n)}$ for exponents less than $2.$ See the remark added to the answer.
